# archi- vs meta- prefix

Tags: etymology, prefix

In English, we use the prefix *meta*, e.g. in metalanguage, to mean that something is one level higher or more abstract.

I read in the preface of a book about the software Metapost that it was a mistake based on a misunderstanding of the title *Metaphysics* by Aristotle, it was just meant to be the book after *Physics*, not a more abstract thing.

I wanted to know if this was correct, and if so, if archi- was a better Greek prefix to express this idea when coining words in Latin.

Comment: Those are prefixes, not suffixes, and they're actually both Greek.

Comment: Cf. *metamorphosis*, i.e. what is made after you change.

Answer (score 4):

From what I learned in my bachelor's programme of philosophy, your etymology of *meta-* is correct, and I have also read this elsewhere. But I have not studied the term myself. It might kind of work to have the intended meaning, though only if it is read as short for *metaphysical*; I would say that reading is less than felicitous.

*Archi-* would be related to Greek *archê* "beginning, first principle, sovereignty, power". I think the sense "first principle" is probably mostly limited to a philosophical context, but I don't see why it could not be extended. However, there exist many words using *arche-/archi-/archo-* (aequivalent forms) meaning "first in time" and "most powerful", so it might not always be read the way you intended it.

I think the most logical praefix would be Latin ***super***, though, which means "over, above". In Greek, that would be *hyper-*, which is etymologically related. Cf. *superorder* in biology, which is a higher order in taxonomy; and *hyperonym*, which is a "higher name", as *fruit* is to *apple*.